# Using a variable in the WHERE Clause

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie in MySQL and PHP. I have a HTML form where I would like to pass 1 variable from to my PHP code and then run a query on my database for the record that holds that variable under the column 'Serial'. I can run it fine when I hard code the 'serial' that I want to look up but when I try with the variable I get an error.

Any help would greatly be appreciated! Or a better way to do this.

Here is my error: `Unknown column 'amg002' in 'where clause'`

Here is my code;

```
$serial= $_POST['Serial'];
echo $serial;

//Connect To Database

$link = mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) OR DIE ('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";

//Select the database - 'SiteInfo'

// Collects data from "SiteInfo" table

//****This is where I am running into the error*** 

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `SiteInfo` WHERE `Serial` ='.$serial; 

// This works!!!

//$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `SiteInfo` WHERE `Serial` ="amg002";';   

$data = mysql_query($sql)
or die(mysql_error());

// puts the "SiteInfo" info into the $info array

$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );

//Print out the contents of the entry

echo "Site Name: ".$info['SiteName'] . "<br /";
Print "Serial Number: ".$info['Serial'] . "<br />";
Print "Location: ".$info['Location'] . "<br />";

// Close the database connection

mysql_close($link); 
echo "Connection Closed. <br />";
```

Comment: It's best to abandon the antiquated `mysql_` functions and switch to a library that offers parameterized queries, e.g. PDO or mysqli.

Comment: You're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Do not continue with this code until you've read up about this and understand how to prevent them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree its a quote issue, but here is how my code would look.

```
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM SiteInfo WHERE Serial = "' . $serial . '"';
```

or

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'SiteInfo; WHERE 'Serial' = \"$serial\"";
```

Comment: There is no quote issue unless SERIAL is string.

Comment: @Sarfraz, from his working example I think that is a safe assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a quote issue:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `SiteInfo` WHERE `Serial` ='.$serial.';
```

should be

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `SiteInfo` WHERE `Serial` ='".$serial."'";
```

Comment: Look at the quotes around `$serial`

Comment: It's recommended to use single-quotes as they are unaffected by the `ANSI_QUOTES` setting.

Comment: I made some changes to the quotes as mentioned above. Try that, now.

Answer (score 0):

It means your variable:

```
$_POST['Serial']
```

is coming empty. You need to run your code if it isn't empty by checking it via `isset` like this:

```
if (isset( $_POST['Serial'])) {
  $serial= $_POST['Serial'];

  // your rest of the code
}
```

Also if `Serial` is string and not a number, you need to put it in quotes, use below query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `SiteInfo` WHERE `Serial` = '$serial'";
```

You can also check out what does your query come up like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `SiteInfo` WHERE `Serial` = '$serial'"; 
echo $sql;
exit;
```

Comment: I echo the $serial at the top and it seems to pass fine. I also put the if statement around my code as suggested and still I have the same error as stated above.

Comment: @user1424236: Try the query that I have posted in my answer. Copy it and use that.